# How to train a model with time series to predict an object's weight?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Let's say I have an object, like a ball and I want to predict its weight. I have a bunch of different sensors that record a time series of the event. Each event is a different ball I would like to predict.

Here is a hypothetical dataset:

[image]

This is an idea of how my data looks. I have much more sensors (s) and a lot more timestamps for each event. What I am trying to do is train a model to predict the weight of the object using the time series. What confuses me is that the weight of the object is constant, so I thought that in order to incorporate it into the model, I should just create a column with the rows being the same. Is this valid?

What kind of algorithms/models should I look into for predicting a single target variable from time series records?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a time series model with the data you provided. However, you can choose what your time step is. If you always have 3 equal readings in succession for each weight (say every 20 minutes), you can change your time step to be one hour intervals.

The main types of models you can try are integrated models like ARIMA, Forecast distance models like regularized linear regressions or tree-based models, or trend/decomposition models such as Prophet.

Comment: But would the method of trying to predict the ball's weight be considered Time Series Forecasting? I had created a model before using a Distributed Random Forest and noticed that the predictions converged towards the actual data by the time it reached the end of the time series. I don't know if I can change my time steps to larger intervals as the data does not always line up the same.

Comment: You can create a regular machine learning model ignoring time (or simply using some featured that happen to be time specific). However, if there is a time component to the weight, do not learn from the future to predict the past. I recommend you try this first if you haven't done time series modeling yet.

Comment: If the values of the features in the previous time period are helpful in predicting the next time period, then time series would be a good approach. If you want to predict tomorrow's weight and you won't know s1 until the end of tomorrow, you would want to use time series.

Comment: Also if you can't change your time steps, that's fine as long as the steps are consistent.

Comment: Lets say I have an event that lasts 5 seconds. I roll a ball into a elastic band. Sensor 1 is the tension of the band, the other sensors could be other data. I have been collecting all the sensor data for the entire 5 seconds. Now that the event is done, I want to see if the predicted weight of the ball is accurate once the data collection has finished. Is this why you believe a regular machine learning model ignoring time could work? Since it's not done in real-time? What happens if for one event the ball contacts the band at second 2 and for another event it contacts the band at second 3?

Comment: Also thank you for your advice, it is very helpful!

Comment: An example of a time series is the temperature measured every hour. Your example seems like independent events that happen to have time in seconds as a feature. Maybe the measurement that interests you is during the maximum compressions of the band. Make sure each row is the correct unit of analysis of a a single event. You're goal is to make a weight prediction for each new event.

Comment: If the answer resolved your question, you can mark it as "accepted" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work